# Ruby Http gem (http client) inside Sinatra POST

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am trying to relay a `GET` request so when the user does a `POST` request to the server then the server does another `GET` request to some other URL and returns the result.

The issue is that when I use `puts` to print the result I see the correct result that I am expecting but the last line (I believe in ruby the last line of the function automatically returns) does not respond to the `POST` request (it returns empty response). Coming from JavaScript I believe it is doing an asynchronous `GET` call and `POST` response is not waiting until `GET` client is finished.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require "http"

my_app_root = File.expand_path( File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/..' )

set :port, 80
set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
set :public_dir,   my_app_root + '/public'


post "/weather" do
  puts HTTP.get('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=milwaukee')  # prints correct result
  HTTP.get('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=milwaukee')       # response of POST method is empty string!
end
```

---

- [link to http gem](https://github.com/httprb/http)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes to

```
post "/weather" do
  puts HTTP.get('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=milwaukee')  # prints correct result
  HTTP.get('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=milwaukee').to_s
end
```

The `HTTP.get` method returns a `HTTP::Response` object rather than a `String` object.

---

From the source code only specific types of object can be returned.

```
 res = [res] if Integer === res or String === res
  if Array === res and Integer === res.first
    res = res.dup
    status(res.shift)
    body(res.pop)
    headers(*res)
  elsif res.respond_to? :each
    body res
  end
  nil # avoid double setting the same response tuple twice
```